# ¿Es correcto llamar "acento" a una tilde?

Tags: ortografía, acentuación, escritura, símbolos

Hice [unas ediciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/13503/revisions) a una publicación modificando las referencias a los *acentos* para usar el término *tilde*.

> 1- Se utiliza por qué formado por dos palabras y <s>acento</s> tilde para preguntas.

Yo asumía (supongo que por tradición) el uso de [*tilde*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZkHNOE8) como el único válido y que *acento* se refería al sonido:

> 1. f. acento (‖ signo ortográfico español). Raúl se escribe con tilde en la u. Era u. t. c. m.
>
> 2. f. Signo en forma de rayita, a veces ondulada, que forma parte de algunas letras, como la ñ, y que antiguamente se usaba en algunas abreviaturas. Era u. t. c. m.  <sub>pongo esta acepción porque me pareció interesante</sub>

Sin embargo, al rato [blonfu me comentó](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39483060#39483060) que tal vez no era necesaria esa corrección:

> veo que has cambiado acento por tilde pero se pueden usar los dos. Yo siempre digo acento
>
> acento: 3. m. Signo ortográfico español consistente en una rayita oblicua que baja de derecha a izquierda (´)

Allí menciona la tercera acepción de [*acento*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0NDBxAs) en el DLE:

> 1. m. Relieve que en la pronunciación se da a una sílaba, distinguiéndola de las demás por una mayor intensidad, una mayor duración o un tono más alto.
>
> 2. m. Signo ortográfico que en algunas lenguas se escribe sobre ciertas vocales para indicar alguna particularidad fonética.
>
> 3. m. Signo ortográfico español consistente en una rayita oblicua que baja de derecha a izquierda (´), y que, siguiendo unas reglas, se escribe sobre determinadas vocales de sílabas con acento, como en *cámara*, *útil*, *allá*.

Por tanto, ¿es equivalente hablar de acento que de tilde a la hora de denotar el signo ortográfico usado sobre las vocales?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Sí**. Efectivamente y como tú mismo indicas, la RAE acepta la palabra *acento* para denominar a la tilde.

De hecho, esa acepción [está recogida desde la primera edición](https://books.google.es/books?id=3NAwv4L6mpwC&dq=editions%3Aj62m8iHvey4C&pg=PA39#v=onepage&q=accento&f=false) del diccionario de autoridades en 1726, e incluso antes.

Si crees que puede llevar a confusión, además de *tilde* también puedes usar *acento ortográfico* o incluso *signo diacrítico* (aunque este último englobaría a otras marcas como la diéresis, el circunflejo, etc.).

Comment: ¿Y de dónde será que saqué yo que no se usaba? Me da la sensación de haberlo oído a mucha gente. ¿Será una sobrecorrección?

Comment: Al ser _acento_ una palabra con distintos "apellidos", genera confusión: [El acento no es lo mismo que la tilde](http://cadenaser.com/emisora/2017/05/08/ser_madrid_sur/1494232175_350225.html) que subtitulan con _Todas las palabras tienen acento ‘prosódico’, aunque no todas tienen el ‘ortográfico’ o tilde_. Por ende, parece que para evitar confusiones puede ser más práctico hacer lo que sugieres y hablar del _acento ortográfico_.

Comment: Servirá de algo notar que en otros lenguajes, la tilde sobre vocales que existe en español es llamada solamente una marca diacrítica, y la marca sobre la ñ una tilde. Inclusive, en mi escuela en México, más comúnmente se le refería a ésta marca sobre vocales como un acento. Como parte de mis experiencias de estudiante, llegué a llamar la tilde sobre vocales como acento y la tilde sobre la ñ como tilde exclusivamente, para evitar confusiones.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando el contexto evita la ambigüedad, se puede decir acento y obviar si se trata de fonético u ortográfico, por ejemplo:

*La palabra pícaro lleva acento.*
Como sabemos que todas las palabras tienen acento fonético pero no todas tienen acento ortográfico, esa oración solo tiene sentido si se refiere al ortográfico.