# When is this symbol (´) used and why?

Tags: ortografía, acentuación, símbolos

When and why is this symbol `´` used in Spanish words? E.g. *producci**ó**n, qu**é**, cu**á**nto, viv**í**s, pa**í**s*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The (´) symbol is called *[tilde](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZkHNOE8)* or *[acento](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0NDBxAs#JYLsPnP)* in Spanish (more specifically: *[acento gráfico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0NDBxAs#6PGgVqI)* and *[acento ortográfico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0NDBxAs#6PKuIGd)*), and the *Ortografía 2010* written by the RAE says the following about its uses [in chapter 3.3](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UebZEkKWvOxFykod):

- Its main use is to specify which syllable of the word is the one stressed. You can see [here the accentuation rules](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/663/12637) for Spanish. So, we can tell apart *ánimo*, *animo* and *animó*. This is called "tilde prosódica" ("prosodic accent").
- It is also used to tell apart words that are written the same but have different functions. So we know that *de* and *dé* are not the same. This is called "tilde diacrítica" ("diacritical accent").

Comment: No me deja editar porque es muy pequeño el cambio, pero "has" en "[...]are written the same but has different[...]" debería ser "have"

Comment: From the discussion in [¿Es correcto llamar “acento” a una tilde?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21845/1674), it may be worth indicating that we tend to use _acento ortográfico_, since _acento_ can be used in other contexts.

Comment: @fedorqui Added to the answer: "acento gráfico" and "acento ortográfico".

Answer (score 2):

That's an [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent) and is used to mark the [stressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)) vowel.