# Fiabilidad de la regla de poner "cojones" tras que/qué para saber si lleva tilde

Tags: acentuación, adverbios

Existe una norma no escrita, en realidad a medio camino entre la norma y la broma, que dice lo siguiente:

> Para saber si hay que poner tilde o no en que/qué, cuando/cuándo, como/cómo, etc., basta con poner *cojones* detrás de la palabra. Si la frase tiene sentido, lleva tilde.

Aparentemente, con algunos ejemplos sencillos parece que la cosa funciona:

> Me gustaría saber *cuando/cuándo* vas a venir.
>
> ✓ Me gustaría saber **cuándo** cojones vas a venir.
>
> Pues iré *cuando/cuándo* me apetezca.
>
> ⊗ Pues iré **cuando** cojones me apetezca.
>
> ---
>
> Nunca nos dijo *donde/dónde* había escondido el tesoro.
>
> ✓ Nunca nos dijo **dónde** cojones había escondido el tesoro.
>
> Eso está *donde/dónde* nos encontramos el tesoro.
>
> ⊗ Eso está **donde** cojones nos encontramos el tesoro.

Sin embargo, me entra la duda de si esto es realmente así en todos los casos. ¿Cuál es la fiabilidad de esta "norma"? ¿Es 100% fiable o se pueden encontrar casos que la contradigan?

---

Nota 1: quien dice *cojones* dice *porras*, *leches* o cualquier otra interjección al uso.

Nota 2: esta norma se aplica a adverbios y pronombres, pero no a los adjetivos:

> ¿*Cuantas/cuántas* normas tengo que poner para que cumplas la ley?
>
> ⊗ ¿**Cuantas** cojones normas tengo que poner para que cumplas la ley?

Comment: ¿Pero qué cojones de pregunta es esta? Pues mola, no conocía esa regla, deberían meterla en el DPD, seguro que la gente lo aprendía mejor así. xD

Comment: Buscando en rae.es algunos ejemplos he visto dos donde no funciona esa regla: *¡Con qué seriedad trabaja!* y *Ya verás qué bien lo pasamos.*

Comment: @blonfu pues ahí quiero llegar: me gustaría desmitificar esta "regla" con ejemplos claros. Ya haciendo la pregunta vi casos en los que no valía, como en el ejemplo de la nota 2. Y si se puede sacar algún conjunto específico de casos en los que funcione, pues averiguar cuál [cojones] es. :-D

Comment: La única regla infalible es anteponer una frase de discurso indirecto.

Comment: @Gustavson ¿podrías citar ejemplos para dejarlo más claro?  e incluso en la pregunta ya mencionabas un caso que no aplicaba, Charlie (⊗ ¿Cuál (cojones) es la fiabilidad de esta "norma"? suena algo extraño)

Comment: En el título, ¿no quieres decir *acento* en lugar de *tilde*?

Comment: @aparente001 Se puede usar cualquiera de las dos palabras, se habló aquí: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21844/es-correcto-llamar-acento-a-una-tilde

Comment: Otra en la que no se cumple: "El por qué de ..."

Comment: @Fustigador Allí "porqué" se escribe junto y es un sustantivo.

Comment: Que alguien le de una galleta, una cerveza, y un auto a este hombre, esta pregunta necesita mas puntos. mi entendimiento del español ha sido expandido

Comment: Gracias @blonfu.

Answer (score 2):

En Argentina usamos sólo ocasionalmente la palabra “cojones” como sustantivo coloquial para significar “coraje”. En preguntas enfáticas, luego de la palabra interrogativa podemos usar, si estamos muy enojados, “carajo” o “mierda”, ambas bastante fuertes.

Más allá de que los hablantes solemos marcar una diferencia en la entonación de la palabra acentuada (más enfática) y la no acentuada (mero nexo), la decisión sobre cómo clasificar esas palabras que pueden ser pronombres, adverbios o adjetivos interrogativos o exclamativos (en cuyo caso llevan tilde) o conjunciones (en cuyo caso no llevan tilde) se simplifica anteponiendo una frase del discurso indirecto y, en caso de que ya la haya, eliminándola y verificando si lo que sigue puede subsistir, tal como está, como pregunta o exclamación **con el mismo sentido de la oración original**:

- Me gustaría saber cuándo vas a venir. (“Me gustaría saber” ya es una frase introductoria de discurso indirecto y, si se la elimina, subsiste la pregunta: “¿Cuándo vas a venir?”, que está incluida en la oración original.)
- Me gustaría recibirte cuando vengas. (Esta pregunta: *“¿Cuándo vengas?” no es gramaticalmente posible.)
- Nunca nos dijo dónde había escondido el tesoro. (Si eliminamos la frase introductoria, subsiste la pregunta: “¿Dónde había escondido el tesoro?”)
- Se quedó quieto donde había escondido el tesoro. (Claramente, la pregunta “¿Dónde había escondido el tesoro?” no está incluida en la oración original: nadie hizo esa pregunta.)
- ¿Cuántas normas tengo que poner para que cumplas la ley? (Se puede pasar a discurso indirecto: “Me pregunto cuántas normas tengo que poner para que cumplas la ley.”)
- Desobedece cuantas normas se le imponen. (La pregunta “¿Cuántas normas se le imponen?” no está implícita en la oración original.)

Answer (score 0):

"Pues iré cuando cojones me apetezca" es una frase correcta y con sentido.

Más ejemplos de que la norma NO es válida:

-Que cojones sea una palabrota no significa que sea un insulto.
-Cuando cojones sea un insulto me avisas, pues como cojones era una palabrota, pensaba que podía usarse como insulto.
...
Etc.