# When talking in English about Spanish orthography, which diacritics does "tilde" cover?

Tags: acentuación, terminología, diacríticos

When speaking in English about Spanish orthography, what diacritics does the word "tilde" cover? Does it only refer to the diacritic on top of "ñ", or does it also cover things like the diacritical mark in "á"? Also, are the two dots on top of "ü" also referred to by the term "tilde"?

Comment: Related: [¿Es correcto llamar “acento” a una tilde?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21844/1674)

Comment: Although it refers to the Spanish orthography, this is a question about the [English.SE], and should hence be asked there.

Comment: @Charlie I think it occupies one of those fairly gray areas and could be asked in either SE.  While it's asking for terminology in English, that terminology is fairly directly related to Spanish, far more so than, say, asking how to say a given Spanish expression in English.

Comment: @walen [¿lo debatimos en Meta?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3090/12637)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In English, *tilde* refers to the symbol **~**, but not diacritics generally.  **´** is technically called an *acute accent*, but because there is no other type of accent in modern Spanish, it's generally just called an *accent*.  And **¨** is called a *dieresis* (it's the same symbol as an *umlaut*, but in English *umlaut* is generally reserved for *modifications* of the vowel sound, whereas *dieresis* can be used to indicate that a vowel should be pronounced as a separate syllable, as an exception to the usual phonetic rules).  So, to sum up:

- **~ tilde** *virgulilla*
- **´ accent** *tilde*
- **¨ dieresis** *diéresis*

Comment: I generally say an accent mark, not just accent.

Answer (score 1):

In Spanish, "[tilde](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZkHNOE8)" refers to the mark for the accent and the wave above the n.

> tilde
>
> De tildar.
>
> 1. f. acento (‖ signo ortográfico español). Raúl se escribe con tilde en la u. Era u. t. c. m.
> 2. f. Signo en forma de rayita, a veces ondulada, que forma parte de algunas letras, como la ñ, y que antiguamente se usaba en algunas
>    abreviaturas. Era u. t. c. m.
> 3. f. Cosa mínima.
> 4. f. p. us. Tacha, nota denigrativa. Era u. t. c. m.
>
> Real Academia Española © Todos los derechos reservados

But all of the marks used in Spanish above the letters are called "[virgulillas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=btCZ7EZ)", as is shown in DRAE's definition:

> virgulilla
>
> Del dim. de vírgula.
>
> 1. f. Signo ortográfico de forma de coma, rasguillo o trazo; p. ej., el apóstrofo, la cedilla, la tilde de la ñ, etc.
> 2. f. Raya o línea corta y muy delgada.
>
> Real Academia Española © Todos los derechos reservados

Best regards.